# How to share my to do list app data between 2 android devices

Tags: android

I am  working on to do list app and I saved data in SQLITE and I want to share app data to my friend who install my app but he away from me with along distance so I can't use Bluetooth and socket.

Please help me and thanks in advance .

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Comment: Ok. So what is your app and SQLITE table? Is it empty? Show your code.

Comment: Fixed spelling.

Comment: Okay, you linked to firebase, so are you using it? That's not sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You could have used your own backend web service and send it through with JSON data. If you do not want to create a backend service, just use firebase cloud real time database which is very suitable for your project. [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) Instead of creating local SQLite database, save your data into the database which is in the cloud, whenever your friend open the activity or application, fetch data from backend service/firebase database whatever you like